# What would be the Bracha Rishona for a certain blended combination of foods?

Tags: blessing, food

According to Ashkenazim: What would be the Bracha Rishona for a mixture of pureed pumpkin, applesauce and cinnamon? It is a smooth puree (no chunks or identifiable bits). The pumpkin and applesauce are in equal parts. One can't identify either the pumpkin or the applesauce. It's a (delicious and nutritious) brown goop.

Many thanks. SHANAH TOVAH! GMAR CHATIMAH TOVAH!

Comment: Borei Pri Ha'Adamah?

Comment: In order for this to be answerable, you would need to provide some more information. Is it a chunky puree or a smooth puree? Are the ingredients all in equal parts? Are you seeking an answer that generally conforms with Ashkenazi or Sepharadi practice?

Comment: A puree that the fruit is no longer recognized is Shehakol.

Comment: @Chatzkel not according to the Rambam and Mehaber...

Comment: Smooth puree. Pumpkin and applesauce in equal parts. Ashkenazi practice. MANY THANKS for guidance!

Answer (score 1):

"pureed ... can't identify ... brown goop" - It's a good thing you wrote "delicious and nutritious"!  I actually make something similar myself using sweet potatoes, apples, cinnamon, a little nutmeg, a pinch of salt, and a little honey. If yours is quite pureed, as it seems to be by your description, I would think the bracha for it would be Shehakol.  Be well, and enjoy your delicious mixture!

Added (from: https://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Soups): "Halachos of Brachos p. 434 quoting Rav Shlomo Zalman Auerbach explained that if the vegetable was blended completely and there's no solid pieces the bracha is shehakol. However, if there's pieces it is haadama."

(Please Note: This is based off of the fact that you specifically wrote applesauce; if there are identifiable hunks/chunks of apples (i.e., not pureed/blended completely), you would have to take HaEtz into consideration, as apples are fruits of a tree. Haadama was regarding the pumpkin.)
(from: https://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Fruits_and_Vegetables: "Apple - HaEtz העץ" and "Pumpkin - HaAdama האדמה" - Source cited: Veten Bracha (Halachos of Brochos by Rabbi Bodner pg 396, chapter 22))

Comment: welcome to Mi Yodeya we look forward to seeing you around. Please note that this site relies heavily on source material for answers. Whilst what you're saying makes sense, it is likely to be viewed as more like a comment.

Comment: I had clicked "Add a comment."  - I am not sure why it got posted as an answer.  I meant it as a comment.  I will try to locate a source for this, since it posted as an answer, instead of as a comment.  Thank you for the information.

Comment: No problem - hatzlacha!

Comment: I added a source.  Have a good day! :)

Comment: I hope that helps!  Be well!  :)

Comment: Yep that's def better!

Comment: Yay!!  Thank you!!

Comment: Thanks so much, Naomi. I had thought if both the apples and the pumpkin were totally pureed and there were no pieces of either identifiable, it had to be a Shehakol. I do puree them fully. That mixture of "sweet potatoes, apples, cinnamon, a little nutmeg, a pinch of salt, and a little honey" sounds delicious. Thanks for the tip and thank you again for your comment. I greatly appreciate it. May I also extend my welcome to you to this marvelous, EXTREMELY BENEFICIAL site/service/forum. It has many caring persons who wish to share their Torah knowledge with others. Shana Tova. Gmar Chatima Tova.

Comment: You are very welcome!!  Shana Tova!!  !!שנה טובה